# UIView drag drop with replace feature [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to do two main views (dropped zone) and two sub views (dragged views) with replacement feature with Move/Drag Gestures,

an example:

```
UIView *mainView;
mainVire.dropped = YES;
```

this let user can drag the second view inside `mainView` and if there is no view inside just dropped it directly and if there is previous view inside just replace between two views.

How could we do like this one if there is an example or just let me know the key to start

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember myself implementing exactly the same feature. Here is my [DraggedButton](https://github.com/OlDor/DraggedButton) class. `MainVC` includes an example of how to use it.

Here is the preview:

[image: Demo CountPages alpha]

Comment: Thanks alot that's what i'm looking for. +1

Comment: Done and by the way you save my time .. Thanks again

Comment: I need help to improve this functionality could you help me on this please?